# Bounding an integral by a Besov norm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, besov-space

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $\eta^\epsilon$ a mollifier, and $B_3^{\alpha, \infty}$ the Besov space. Define
$$I_\epsilon(x) = \int \eta^\epsilon(y)\big(f(x-y)-f(x)\big)^2 dy$$
Using the inequality
$$\|f(\cdot + y) - f(\cdot)\|_{L^3} \leq C |y|^\alpha \|f\|_{B_3^{\alpha, \infty}} \tag{1}$$
I would like to show that
$$\|I_\epsilon\|_{L^{3/2}} \leq C \epsilon^{2\alpha}\|f\|^2_{B_3^{\alpha,\infty}}$$

Unravelling the definitions gives
$$\|I_\epsilon\|_{L^{3/2}} = \Bigg[ \int \Bigg( \int \eta^\epsilon(y) \big(f(x-y) - f(x)\big)^2 dy\Bigg)^{3/2} dx \Bigg]^{2/3}.$$

My idea is to somehow get the $\frac32$ inside the integral and then use [Hölder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) to get two separate integrals. From there I can use the fact that $\eta^\epsilon$ is a mollifier so its integral is one, and I can use the inequality $(1)$ to take care of the second integral. However I am having trouble with the exponent being outside the integral in the first step.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ingredient you're missing is [Minkowski's integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality), which lets you move the $\frac32$ inside the integral and interchanges the order of integration. This gives
\begin{align*} \lVert I_{\varepsilon} \rVert_{L^{\frac32}(\mathbb R^3)} 
&\leq \int_{\mathbb R^3} \left( \int_{\mathbb R^3} \lvert\eta^{\varepsilon}(y)\rvert^{\frac32} \lvert f(x-y) - f(x)\rvert^3 \,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac23} \,\mathrm{d}y\\
& =\int_{\mathbb R^3}  \eta^{\varepsilon}(y) \lVert f(\cdot - y ) - f \rVert_{L^3}^2\,\mathrm{d}y\\
& \leq C\int_{\mathbb R^3}  \eta^{\varepsilon}(y)  \lvert y \rvert^{2\alpha} \lVert f \rVert_{B_3^{\alpha,\infty}}^2\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&\leq C \varepsilon^{2\alpha} \lVert f \rVert_{B_3^{\alpha,\infty}}^2
\end{align*}
as required, where we have applied said inequality in the first line.

**Edited to add**: Note that in the last line, we used the fact that $\eta^{\varepsilon}$ is supported on a ball of radius $\varepsilon$, so on said support we have $\lvert y \rvert^{2\alpha} \leq \varepsilon^{2\alpha}$. Then we use the fact that $\eta^{\varepsilon}$ integrates to one, as it is a mollifier.

Comment: Thank you very much, this inequality is exactly what I needed. Also, how did you get rid of the $4/3$ exponent on $\eta^\epsilon$ going from the first line to the second? And then how did you conclude $\int \eta^\epsilon(y) |y|^{2\alpha}dy \leq \epsilon^{2\alpha}$?

Comment: After applying the Minkowski integral inequality I think the integrand should be $|\eta|^{3/2}|f(x-y) - f(x)|^3$ so that we have $$\leq C \|f\|^2_{B_3^{\alpha, \infty}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |\eta^\epsilon(y)| |y|^{2\alpha} dy$$ and this is where I am not stuck. I am also wondering how these integrals (such as my original definition for $I_\epsilon$) makes sense given that $f$ is vector-valued. Would this require a dot product in between?

Comment: Typo in my last comment sorry. I meant to write "this is where I am now stuck".

Comment: @CBBAM You're right with the exponent for $\eta^{\varepsilon}$, that was a typo that I've corrected. For the second part I've added a brief explanation for how we get the $\varepsilon^{2\alpha}$ term. The fact that it's vectorial shouldn't make a difference, as you're estimating $\lvert f(x-y) - f(x) \rvert^2$, where I use $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ for the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understand everything now. The one point I'm still confused about is a more general point about mollifying vector-valued functions. Is $\eta: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and the convolution is done component wise (i.e. $\eta * f = (\eta_1 * f_2, \eta_2 * f_2, \eta_3 * f_3)$ or is $\eta: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $\eta * f = (\eta * f_2, \eta * f_2, \eta_3 * f)$? I'm guessing such integral inequalities are supposed to be interpreted component wise?

Comment: @CBBAM It will be the latter, as mollifiers are scalar and non-negative (which I implicitly use in the proof). I assume also that in your definition of $I_{\varepsilon}$ you should have $\lvert f(x-y) - f(x) \rvert^2$, as otherwise it's not clear how to square it.

Comment: I am following a paper which defines $I_\epsilon$ without the $| \cdot |$. I was confused about this as well. I assumed the integral was to be interpreted component wise so that $$\Big(I_\epsilon(x)\Big)_i = \int \eta^\epsilon(y)\big(f_i(x-y)-f_i(x)\big)^2 dy$$ but I am not sure if this is correct or standard.

Comment: Actually in the original paper it is written as $$I_\epsilon(x) = \int \eta^\epsilon(y)\big(f(x-y)-f(x)\big) \otimes \big(f(x-y)-f(x)\big) dy$$

Comment: @CBBAM I see, in that case you can use the pointwise bound $\lvert a \otimes a \rvert \leq \lvert a \rvert^2$  (possibly up to a constant depending on your norm on these tensors) to straightforwardly estimate $I_{\varepsilon} \leq \int \eta^{\varepsilon} \lvert f(x-y) - f(x) \rvert^2 \,\mathrm{d}y$, and then proceed in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. If I may ask just one more question, so $I_\epsilon$ is not interpreted component wise, rather we use the Cauchy-Schwartz identity you provided where $|f|^2$ is the usual Euclidean magnitude $f_1^2 + f_2^2 + f_3^2$?

Comment: @CBBAM I meant to write $\lvert I_{\varepsilon} \rvert$ in my previous comment, but $I_{\varepsilon}$ is viewed component-wise (it is tensor-valued), but it is bounded from above with the scalar integral I wrote.

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help and patience!